# Update column from inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of posts from a forum, basically there is one row for the posting of a pdf file , then there is another row for the posting of the image url that goes with the pdf.  So I took all the rows out of posts table and inserted them into Item table if they are a pdf.  Now I have a column in Item table that I want to get filled with the row in the posts table that has the image basically I want

```
UPDATE Item i Set i.ImageUrl = p.guid
JOIN posts p ON i.old_id = p.parent_post
where p.PostType = 'image'
```

I have not been able to find a good example anywhere that is an Update that uses a join and has a WHERE clause ,  does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax in SQL Server looks more like this:

```
UPDATE i
    SET ImageUrl = p.guid
    FROM Item i JOIN
         posts p
         ON i.old_id = p.parent_post
    WHERE p.PostType = 'image';
```